# How to fit a model using least squares minimisation in matplotlib (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, curve-fitting, least-squares

I am trying to fit a model to a spectrum (see below) using the least squares minimisation in matplotlib. The spectrum contains features characterised by the following curves:

[image]

[image]

Since the spectrum contains features of an exponential and Gaussian function, I combined the first two characteristics (the Gaussian and exponential functions) and fitted the model using the least squares minimisation method in python. See the code below.

```
#The model to fit to the data
def f(a, x):
      return  a[0]*np.exp(-((x - a[1])**2)/(2*(a[2])**2)) + a[0]*np.exp(-a[1]*(x - a[2])) +a[0]

#Residuals
def err(a, x, y):
    return f(a, x) - y

xdata, ydata = np.loadtxt('data2.csv', delimiter = ',', unpack = True) 

#Performing the fit
a0 = [0.1, 1, 1] #initial guess

a, success = leastsq(err, a0, args = (xdata, ydata))

x = np.linspace(xdata.min(), xdata.max(), 1000)

plt.plot(x, f(a, x), 'r-')
plt.step(xdata,ydata)
#plt.title('Spectrum')
```

Output:

[image]

The curve I am trying to fit on the spectrum is shown in red but it's not oscillating around the peak. I tried increasing or decreasing the initial guesses but that does not help. Is my model wrong perhaps? Or am I missing something in my code? Please help, your help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

[Link to the data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UcINmpNZopsiiZsVymTlx4_4A1mVGGRC)

Comment: I think the function you're fitting is not convex, that is to say you aren't guaranteed to converge to the correct answer so you need to provide a good starting point for the leastsq optimizer. Try using a more sensible guess for your initial parameters  like `a0 = [.1, 800, 100]`

Comment: Though I think you may also need to reconsider what  a_0 is in your model. You're trying to require a_0 to be both the floor of the data and the height of the peak which doesn't seem possible. Are you meant to have normalized your data?

Comment: No, the data must not be normalised. I am meant to just fit a curve to the data.

Comment: I tried those type of guesses but I just get a flat line when I assign the variables to large values.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the a_x parameters are not meant to be shared between the three equations. In other words, I think it is impossible to model that data with only 3 parameters.